# Is it possible to wrap a single jQuery document ready event around a ScriptBundle in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

In order to avoid calling the jQuery .ready() event multiple times for each file within an Asp.Net MVC ScriptBundle, is it possible to wrap the ready event around the entire bundle?

Each of the following files contains the **$( document ).ready(function() { }** code around the JavaScript code within...

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/core.js",
                        "~/Scripts/application.js",
                        "~/Scripts/controls.js",
                        "~/Scripts/custom.js"));
```

I could create two js files, one which contains **$( document ).ready(function() {**, the other containing just a closing parenthesis. Then add these files to the start and end of the existing bundle, but is there a better method?

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485953/wrap-all-coffescript-files-in-a-jquery-document-ready-function-after-concatenati) has been asked for CoffeScript concatenation of files, but I can't translate the solution easily to Asp.Net bundling.

Comment: You can't simply do that. You need to use a module pattern in your JS for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at the JavaScript files that you wrote (not `jquery-{version}.js`), then create a method that will be publicly accessible from outside your files that you call on the page.

```
var Application = (function () {
    // All your code

    function init() {
        // All your code that you have inside $(document).ready()
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
}());
```

Do the above for all of your files, then on any page that needs it, or in your _Layout page if it's going to run on every page have the following at the bottom

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Application.init();
        // etc for the other files.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is an approach that will close the scope of everything else inside that file. So just be wary that if you do have something in those files that you want to access outside of the file, you'll need to add it inside the `return` block like the init. It's a good habit to get into as it minimizes your footprint in the global space.

Comment: I take it this is the JavaScript Module Pattern? Are there are online tutorials you recommend to get myself up to speed? If you don't have time to post any I understand and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Correct. I didn't use a tutorial, I read the book "Expert Javascript" by Mark E. Daggett to pick up a ton of skills and practices with writing cleaner, more extensible JavaScript. Granted, this was after JavaScript: The Good Parts.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll take a look.